# Release React-native android build crashes on launch when generated after gradle clean

Tags: android, react-native

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
             Process: com.packagename.example, PID: 14791
             k3.c: `View` has no propType for native prop `RCTView.marginStart` of native type `mixed`
             If you haven't changed this prop yourself, this usually means that your versions of the native code and JavaScript code are out of sync_status. Updating both should make this error go away., stack:
             verifyPropTypes@25593:22
             requireNativeComponent@24924:42
             <unknown>@23214:37
             loadModuleImplementation@106:12
             <unknown>@43753:19
             loadModuleImplementation@106:12
             <unknown>@50964:27
             loadModuleImplementation@106:12
             <unknown>@50699:32
             loadModuleImplementation@106:12
             <unknown>@1305:13
             loadModuleImplementation@106:12
             guardedLoadModule@63:45
             global code@57016:9
             
                at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(Unknown Source:75)
                at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(Unknown Source:27)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:148)
                at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:147)
                at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0)
                at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Any idea why we get this error on apps that are build after gradle clean command and not if we rebuild the app again without clean.